# Buffering serial ouput and parsing JSON

Tags: rust, serde

I'm new to rust and struggling with an issue. I'm looking to read output from serial and convert it to JSON.

Below is the section of code that reads in the serial output.

```rust
match serialport::open(&port_name) {
    Ok(mut port) => {
        let mut serial_buf: Vec<u8> = vec![0; 1000];
        loop {
            match port.read(serial_buf.as_mut_slice()) {
                Ok(t) => handle_event(&serial_buf[..t]),
                Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::TimedOut => (),
                Err(e) => print!("Port read error: {}\n", e), 
            };
        }
    }
    Err(e) => {
        println!("Failed to open \"{}\". Error: {}", port_name, e);
        ::std::process::exit(1);
    }
};
```

Next that output is passed to serde to be parsed. However the output it gets isn't always the complete JSON string so serde breaks. I believe I need to buffer the response here but struggling to fit that in.

```rust
fn handle_event(buf: &[u8]) {
    let e_str = match str::from_utf8(buf) {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => { print!("Str conversion error: {}\n", e); return; }, 
    };

    let e = match serde_json::from_str::<Event>(e_str) {
        Ok(e) => e,
        Err(e) => { print!("JSON parse error: {}\n", e); return; },
    };

    print!("{}", e.name);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please can you include the definition of Event and maybe a sample data.

Comment: This should help: https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_reader.html

Comment: Probably, the easiest way to go is to insert a delimiter. Either a newline (if you can ensure the json is minified), or perhaps a null byte. Then you can buffer the data until the delimiter appears.

Comment: As an aside, JSON is probably not the right format for this type of application. Consider instead using sequences of fixed-length  messages, or an encoding with built-in unambiguous EOF delimiters.